# Binding Generic List Array to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list, gridview

Hi I have a List which returns an array of "Question".  My question is how can I bind this to a grid view?  When I try to call Question.Ordinal I get that it does not exist in the data source.  I am using the following code:

```
GridView1.DataSource = myList.GetQ();
GrdiView1.DataBind();
```

myList.GetQ() returns a List which is an array of "Question".

When I set the column DataField to "!" I get the object Question.  My question is how can I get the objects property?  I tried "!.Ordinal" does not work.  I was reading this post for reference, [here](http://www.mikepope.com/blog/AddComment.aspx?blogid=1419), any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following syntax:

```
<%# ((MyObject)Container.DataItem).MyField %>
```

Comment: I get a parse error:
Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField does not have a DataBinding event.

Answer (score 1):

Just set it directly to Ordinal, as the first examples in the post you just linked to:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="CustId" />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
   <asp:BoundField HeaderText="City" DataField="City" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Say:

```
<asp:BoundField HeaderText="A Header" DataField="APropertyOfQuestion" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you must be define the property member of class, as a propery ie

```
public string ProductName
{
    get
    {
        return _productName;
    }
    set { }

}
```

Or VB

public property ProductName() as string
set ..

get...

end property

important: Is Required defined get method