# Binding a column within a generic List to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, gridview

I tried reading all the articles and tried the solutions as well did not work for me.

One of the solutions i tried

[Binding Generic List Array to GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/619477/binding-generic-list-array-to-gridview).

The new project file that I created using your tweeked sample code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SharePointProject2
{
public class abc
{
      public string customername { get; set; }
    public List<def> DEF { get; set; }
}

public class def
{
    public string materialcode { get; set; }
}
```

}

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Collections.Generic;


namespace SharePointProject2.testing
{
public partial class testingUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            List<abc> test1 = new List<abc>();
            List<def> test2 = new List<def>();
            test2.Add(new def() { materialcode = "something" });
            test1.Add(new abc() { customername = "anything", DEF = test2 });
            GridView1.DataSource = test1;
            GridView1.DataBind();

    }


}
```

}

```
<%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="testingUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="SharePointProject2.testing.testingUserControl" %>  

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Charge Code">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"     Text='<%# ((List<def>)(Eval("DEF")))[0].materialcode %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

</Columns>
```

When I compile the code above, this is the error messsage

The type or namespace name 'def' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Don't forget to upvote your answers if it was helpful though.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Sorry I had misread a lot of your question.  Your example does not compile at all so I made a quick test app example to illustrate the solution:

```
public class def   {   public string materialcode{get;set;}   }
public class abc
{
    public string customername { get; set; }
    public List<def> DEF { get; set; }
}

List<abc> test1 = new List<abc>();
List<def> test2 = new List<def>();
test2.Add(new def() { materialcode = "something" });
test1.Add(new abc() { customername = "anything", DEF = test2 });

grdTest.DataSource = test1;
grdTest.DataBind();
```

I have tested the above and it works.  Leave a comment if you require any clarification.

**EDIT:**  The following should get you up and running, and is in my opinion, a cleaner way of implementing custom binding and allows you to debug the issue much easier.

Change your `Label` in your `ItemTemplate` to the following:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblchargecode" runat="server"
    Text='' OnDataBinding="lblchargecode_DataBinding"></asp:Label>
```

Add the `DataBinding` method to your codebehind:

```
protected void lblchargecode_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)sender;
    lbl.Text = ((List<def>)(Eval("DEF")))[0].materialcode;
}
```

Also make sure to check your includes.  You need to make sure that your code knows about the `def` class so include a `using` statement where required or fully qualify it.

Comment: Hello Kelsy,

Thanks for your reply.

I changed it to   

    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Charge Code">  
    <ItemTemplate>
  
    <asp:Label ID="lblchargecode" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval(("materialcode").ToString())%    >'></asp:Label>--%>
    </ItemTemplate>  
    </asp:TemplateField>  

I am getting an error stating that materialcode is not a property.

Comment: @Janaki I have updated the question again, I forgot to include the binding statement for your `Label`.  See edit as it should work and I have tested it to verify.

Comment: <asp:Label ID="lblchargecode" runat="server"     Text='<%# ((List<def>)(Eval("DEF")))[0].materialcode %>'></asp:Label>    doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Janaki Honestly I don't know what else I can do for you.  First off, 'Doesnt work' is not very helpful to anyone.  Be descriptive to the point of being overly verbose even.  I have spent a lot of time making a working example.  If you can't get it to work you need to post your EXACT code (enough to get it to build in a test app) and your EXACT error.  You need to understand the solution and not just to cut and paste it and hope it works.

Comment: I have created a new project with your tweeked sample code , it still says that def does not belong..here is the complete code of what I have in my project file

Comment: I have edited my sample code that I had posted yesterday for your review. kindly check...

Comment: @Janaki I have update the code to get it to work.  I never do inline `<#%  %>` in my binding so substitute the `OnDataBinding` method.

Comment: @Kelsi I compiled the code as you suggested without inline binding and it works , I am so happy , Just a last question to you for every column in def I need to have a code set up in the code behind file , I mean ..suppose there is another item customer id in list<def> then I should have protected void lblcustomerid_DataBinding(object sender, System.EventArgs e) in the code behind with <asp:Label ID="lblcustomerid" runat="server"     Text='' OnDataBinding="lblcustomerid_DataBinding"></asp:Label> . So sorry to bother you so much...

Comment: @Janaki you can do it on a case by case basis. You can use normal binding methods if you want. I only use the `OnDataBinding` when I want to do something that isn't straight forward like your case here. Also, don't forget to set this as the 'accepted answer'/upvote it... all this work I need some recognition :)

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Charge Code">  
<ItemTemplate>

<asp:Label ID="lblchargecode" runat="server" Text='<%# ((List<def>) Eval("DEF"))[0].materialcode %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>  
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Eval returns object you have to cast it to original type then use it .