# What is the easiest way to display a table of data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Coming from PHP background.  What would be the easiest (best?) way to display a table of data populated in C#?  The format of the data could be modified as required, right now, I am thinking 2D list to store the data.

Gridview is nice and all but I haven't found a way to use a C# List as it's data source.

No real feature is required.  I can implement my own editor / inserter, etc.

Comment: GridView is the standard; using a DataTable to bind the data.

Comment: What exact problem are you having with GridView? Also, how would you have done this using PHP?

Comment: Use ListView Control. You will have full control over rendered html by using this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gridview is what you need.  To bind to a list, you just set the list as the datasource and away you go:

```
List<x> myList = GetList();

myGrid.DataSource = myList;
myGrid.DataBind();
```

Or use an ObjectDataSource control on the page instead...

Comment: How do I map the columns from my 2D List to the gridview?

Comment: There are a few steps through doing that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/619477/binding-generic-list-array-to-gridview

Answer (score 0):

DataTable could be another best option
as it can support the specific columns of the table or you can manage the whole table in the DataTable
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
now you can store your table from the database into this and can use it as a data source for your listview or gridview